# Recordset Paging Navigation

Tags: asp-classic

I have a recordset paging navigation and a textbox where I input some text. What i want is when I click the next button on the paging navigation the text will still remain there until i hit the clear button (thats the only time it will be remove on the textbox). Is there anyway to do it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Jquery you can achieve this.

On Button Click event you can clear text box

```
$("#btnID").click(function() {
$("#textboxID").val('');
});
```